Which scripture mentiones about Goddess Gandheswari?
Sometimes ago, i have saw the picture of a goddess named Gandheswari and she is considered as the one saves her devotee from an asura.
But, Which scriptures mention about her? If yes, is it also had the story of Goddess Gandheswari saved her devotee?

Gandheshwari is the kuladevi of the gamdhabanika (spice & perfume trader) caste of Bengali Hindu society, who perform her annual worship on Vaisakhi purnima. Due to not belonging to the abovementioned group, nothing can be told about her. Her iconography strikingly resembles that of Vanadurga in the Sharadatilaka Tantra & is propitiated used the 8-lettered Muladurga mantra.
